# CFloop through query and apply each result to a variable

Tags: loops, coldfusion-9, cfloop

I'm drawing a bit of a blank at the moment on looping, so a pointer would be greatly appreciated.

1. I'm running a query for a list of names in a table given before a specific time.
2. I need to loop through those results and set a variable `<cfset file2 = (result from query)` so this code can execute:

   > ```
   > >  <cfexecute name="C:\Program Files
   > > (x86)\neeviaPDF.com\PDFcompress\cmdLine\CLcompr.exe"
   > > arguments="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testingFolder\PDFCompression2\pdf\#arguments.file2#
   > > C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testingFolder\PDFCompression2\pdf\ResultPDF3.pdf
   > > -co -ci jpg -cq 10 -gi jpg -gq 10 -mi jbig2 -mq 1" outputfile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testingFolder\PDFCompression2\output.txt"
   > > timeout="250"> </cfexecute>
   > ```

It will then loop through the results of the query setting the variable file2 to each result, thus compressing the files with those names.

Comment: So which part are you struggling with? :) Sounds like you just need a basic query loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers and there is no "final code". The answer was use a simple query loop.  This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which resolved my issue.

```
<cfquery name="qryGetFilesJustUploaded" datasource="#request.dsn#">                                         <!--- Limit to filed with pdf file type endings --->
SELECT fileupload
  FROM [First_Title_Services_Dev].[dbo].[upload_many]
  WHERE filedate >= '#dateTimeStamp#' AND fileupload Like '% .pdf'
</cfquery>

<!--- Next Set a loop function to run cfexecute--->
<cfloop query="qryGetFilesJustUploaded">
<cfset pdf_file_name = 'qryGetFileJustUploaded' />
<cfexecute name="C:\Program Files (x86)\neeviaPDF.com\PDFcompress\cmdLine\CLcompr.exe"
arguments="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testingFolder\PDFCompression2\pdf\#pdf_file_name# C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testingFolder\PDFCompression2\pdf\#pdf_file_name# -co -ci jpg -cq 10 -gi jpg -gq 10 -mi jbig2 -mq 1"
outputfile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testingFolder\PDFCompression2\output.txt"
timeout="250">
</cfexecute>

</cfloop>
```

Comment: You do not need anything more than a basic query loop ie `<cfloop query="..">`. No need to create extra variables. Just use the existing `query.columnName`.  Since you already mentioned `cfloop` in the question tags, it is still not clear what issue you were having ;-)

Comment: Loops and I have a checkered past if that makes sense. :-D

Comment: Haha ;-) Just keep in mind that while there is nothing technically wrong with creating extra variables within a query loop, it is usually unnecessary. So be sure it is done for a good reason, like increased readability. Otherwise it is just code "noise" ;-)